# Add js to MapBox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

Currently I have a mapbox map that outputs markers, each marker popup has a link within it, once clicked it will only show markers relative to the original marker clicked. [image]

The view areas link is structured like:

`<p class="view_areas" id="123">View Areas</p>`

And the resulting js like:

`$('.view_areas').click(function() {console.log('test')})`

However clicking the link fails to produce any sort of result from the console. Is this because the marker doesn't exist on the DOM until it is clicked? I've also attempted doing:

`<p class="view_areas" id="123" onClick="view_areas()">View Areas</p>
<script>function view_areas(){ console.log('test'); }</script>`

But this produces a function not found error. Basically the link will serve as a toggle, however because of the large amount of markers that will be on the screen, using layers would be a bit impractical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly because the element is dynamically added to the page **after** DOM load. You can use [event delegatation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to target the `.view_areas` elements by attaching the click handler to a parent element, such as `document` and using the following syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_areas', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

This strategy can be used for basically any dynamically added elements and will target the children elements specified in the 2nd parameter of `on()`. If you know that the modal/dialogs are contained within a specific element that is **not** dynamically added to the page, you can target that instead of the `document`/`body`/etc.

```
$('.somePermanentContainerElement').on('click', '.view_areas', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You are my hero